# How to convert an HTML template into CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Im newbie. Can you help me how to convert html template to cakephp. Thank you. also do you have tutorials about cake php.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not provide end-to-end tutorials or personalized tutoring services.  There exist tutorials and examples via some Google searches to find much of the introductory information you're looking for.  Once you get started with the technologies in question and begin making an attempt to build something, if you encounter a specific error or unexpected result in your code then we can help you understand and resolve that specific problem.  To learn more about this community you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Nico Haase. In src/template i already made head.ctp, header.ctp, index.ctp. Im stuck at i dont how to set it with controller and to config/route.php

Comment: Here's the [official tutorials](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples.html), they should help get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There is a folder in the src with the name Template(src/template). Create a ctp file in the template folder with a simple html code like index.ctp .

For more reference:

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html